# Plotly and left alignment

Tags: r, plotly

I am working with Plotly. I have a double asterisk under this bar chart. Below you can see code and chart

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes*", "whale**", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
) |> 
  layout(annotations = 
           list(x = 0, y =-0.131, 
                text = "Note: * The tallest animal,Unsurprisingly, the giraffe is the world's tallest living animal by standing height. Male giraffes can measure up to 6 meters or almost 20 feet, but with a height of up to 5.2 meters or 17 feet \n Note: ** Тhe longest animal" ,
                showarrow = F, 
                xref='paper', 
                yref='paper')
  )
```

[image]

In the above pic, you can see that the second note has `center alignment`. So I want to change this with `left alignment`. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `align` in your `annotations` like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes*", "whale**", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
) |> 
  layout(annotations = 
           list(x = 0, y =-0.131, 
                text = "Note: * The tallest animal,Unsurprisingly, the giraffe is the world's tallest living animal by standing height. Male giraffes can measure up to 6 meters or almost 20 feet, but with a height of up to 5.2 meters or 17 feet \n Note: ** Тhe longest animal" ,
                showarrow = F, 
                xref='paper', 
                yref='paper',
                align = "left")
  )
```

Output:

[image]